# Time is the potential?

Tags: quantum-gravity

Perhaps time can be expressed as

$$ t = \frac {Gh} {c ^ 4} \int \frac {dS} {r} $$

Where S is the entropy of entanglement of an arbitrary closed surface. r is the radius to the surface point. Integration over a closed surface.

This is very similar to the analogy. Time behaves as a potential, and entropy as a charge.

From this formula there are several possible consequences.

1. Bekenstein Hawking entropy for the event horizon. Light cone case

$$ ct = r $$

$$ S = \frac {c ^ 3} {Gh} r ^ 2 $$

2. Gravitational time dilation. The case if matter inside a closed surface processes information at the quantum level according to the Margolis-Livitin theorem.

$$ dI = \frac {dM c ^ 2t} {h} $$

$$ \Delta t = \frac {Gh} {c ^ 4} \int \frac {dI} {r} = \frac {GM} {rc ^ 2} t $$

3. The formula is invariant under Lorentz transformations.
4. If this definition is substituted instead of time, then the interval acquires a different look, which probably indicates a different approach of the Minkowski pseudometric with a complex plane

$$ s ^ 2 = (l ^ 2_ {p} \frac {S} {r}) ^ 2-r ^ 2 $$

Where is the squared length of Planck

$$ l ^ 2_ {p} = \frac {Gh} {c ^ 3} $$

Is such an interpretation possible? Sincerely, 
 Kuyukov V.P.

Comment: https://physicsdiscussionforum.org/download/file.php?id=1419